# « Mettre dans l'oreille du chat »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, france

Que signifie l'expression « *mettre dans l'oreille du chat* » ? Aucune source sur le Web ne donne de résultat.

Voilà le contexte dans lequel on peut lire cette expression.

> *La petite Fadette*, George Sand.
>
> Enfin, par tous les moyens que vous pourrez imaginer, empêchez-les de se confondre l'un avec l'autre et de s'accoutumer à ne pas se passer l'un de l'autre. Ce que je vous dis là, j'ai grand'peur que vous ne le mettiez dans l'oreille du chat; mais si vous ne le faites pas, vous vous en repentirez grandement un jour.
> La mère Sagette parlait d'or et on la crut. On lui promit de faire  comme elle disait, et on lui fit un beau présent avant de la renvoyer.

On pourrait penser que ça signifie « oublier », mais  il y a d'autres possibilités comme par exemple « ne pas tenir compte de ».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ce n'est pas une expression courante en France. Je ne l'avais jamais rencontrée. En fouillant un peu, je ne sais pas si c'était une expression courante (probablement régionale) ou une invention de Sand.

En français moderne, il y a une expression courante « ***donner sa langue au chat*** », qui signifie « renoncer à deviner ». Historiquement, cette expression parlait de chien et non de chat. [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/chien) et d'autres citent Mme de Sévigné :

> Ne sauriez-vous le deviner ? jetez-vous votre langue aux chiens ?

De manière générale, en français, si on jette quelque chose aux chiens, c'est qu'on renonce à le manger, parce qu'on le trouve inutile ou pas assez bon pour un humain.

Il n'est pas clair pour moi comment l'expression a dérivé du chien au chat. [Une comparaison de fréquences à l'écrit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=langue+au+chat%2Clangue+aux+chats%2Clangue+au+chien%2Clangue+aux+chiens&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) montre que la « langue au chat » est apparue vers 1860 et a mis quelques dizaines d'années à remplacer la « langue aux chiens ». La « langue aux chiens » a complètement disparu du français moderne, au moins en France (je ne l'ai jamais entendue). Elle survit peut-être dans certaines régions, mais à l'écrit, dans des livres modernes, je ne la trouve que comme référence à une expression historique.

Certaines sources attribuent « donner sa langue au chat » à Sand, mais ce n'est pas le cas, puisqu'on la trouve plus tôt, par exemple [dans un dictionnaire italien-français publié en 1777](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nouveau_Dictionnaire_Fran%C3%A7ois_Italien/9uhMAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22langue+au+chat%22&pg=PA324&printsec=frontcover) et dans un [dictionnaire allemand-français publié en 1798](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Neues_Deutsch_Franz%C3%B6sisches_und_Franz%C3%B6/o3lpAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22langue+au+chat%22&pg=PA2968&printsec=frontcover), mais dans les deux cas avec un sens plus général : ne pas utiliser sa langue, rester muet. Un [article publié en 1866](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_Interm%C3%A9diaire_des_chercheurs_curieux/F88oyWx_48YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22langue+au+chat%22&pg=PT77&printsec=frontcover) sur cite « donner sa langue au chat » comme une variante de « jeter sa langue aux chiens » utilisée dans le Blaisois (région de Blois). Sand n'a donc pas inventé cette expression, mais il est possible qu'elle l'ait popularisée.

L'expression est probablement à rapprocher de « est-ce que le chat t'a mangé ta langue ? », expression [attestée en français](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Faune_populaire_de_la_France/MA0JAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22langue+au+chat%22&pg=PA107&printsec=frontcover) mais que je n'ai personnellement jamais rencontrée. Elle a le même sens que l'expression anglaise « *Has the cat got your tongue?* » : question rhétorique que l'on pose à quelqu'un qui ne répond pas.

Les chats sont historiquement associés à la sorcellerie. Il est possible que ces deux expressions dérivent de l'idée que le chat aurait magiquement pris la langue de quelqu'un, ce qui l'empêcherait de parler. Mais ce n'est là qu'une hypothèse, je n'ai aucun élément de preuve.

Et ***l'oreille du chat***, alors ? L'expression se comprend bien comme complémentaire de la langue au chat. Si on donne sa langue au chat, on ne parle pas, et le chat non plus. Si on dit quelque chose au chat, le chat ne le répétera pas. Je ne trouve pas d'utilisation de cette expression avant *La petite Fadette*. (Il existait une expression « le nid d'une souris dans l'oreille d'un chat », une métaphore pour quelque chose d'impossible, citée par exemple par [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/chat), expression elle aussi disparue du français moderne. Mais je ne pense pas qu'il y ait un lien.) Et même après, ce ne semblent qu'être des citations de Sand. Donc je pense que c'est une variation créée par Sand, inspirée de « donner sa langue au chat ».

Puisque l'expression semble provenir d'un texte unique, seuls la construction de l'expression et ce contexte peuvent aider à comprendre le sens. Les deux conduisent à penser que cela veut dire que ce qui est mis dans l'oreille du chat ne sera répété à personne. Et puisque la personne qui a reçu cette lettre aura *mis* les mots dans l'oreille du chat, elle ne les aura pas gardés. Donc « j'ai grand'peur que vous ne le mettiez dans l'oreille du chat » signifie « j'ai grand'peur que vous fassiez comme si je n'avais rien dit », « j'ai grand'peur que vous n'en teniez pas compte ». C'est un oubli, mais un oubli volontaire.

P.S. On trouve bien quelques sources en ligne, mais aucune ne fait plus que spéculer sur la relation entre l'oreille (chez Sand) et la langue (plus généralement).

- [Jean Pruvost, *Donner sa langue au chat ou au chien ?*](https://www.canalacademies.com/emissions/le-sens-des-mots/mot-pour-mot/donner-sa-langue-au-chat-ou-au-chien)
- [Magazine d'Ouest-France, *Donner sa langue au chat : explications*](https://lemagduchat.ouest-france.fr/dossier-856-donner-langue-chat.html)
- [Blog « La Langue française », *Donner sa langue au chat : définition et origine de l’expression
  *](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/expressions/donner-sa-langue-au-chat)
- [Blog « Expressio », *donner sa langue au chat*](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/donner-sa-langue-au-chat)

Comment: Je ne sais pas vraiment s'il s'agit de « ne pas tenir compte » ; parmi la collection de réflexions très intéressantes que donne votre référence Littré sur le mot « chat » je viens de trouver quelque chose de très singulier : « C'est le nid d'une souris dans l'oreille d'un chat, se dit d'une chose impossible. ». Ne se pourrait-il pas qu'il y ait une connexion plus directe à cet adage-là ? Par exemple « grand'peur que ce ne vous soit pas possible »

Comment: @LPH Comme je je dis dans ma réponse, je ne vois pas de lien. C'est le rapprochement du chat et de la souris qui fait l'impossibilité, pas l'oreille du chat seule.

Comment: Oui, bien sûr, dans l'adage le nid de souris est essentiel, mais qui sait si George Sand n'a pas cherché à simplifier l'adage en s'en servant, en ne gardant qu'un minimum dans le but de ne pas alourdir sa phrase ? De toute façon, selon l'opinion générale, on doit  conclure que ce qu'il y a de plus probable c'est l'interprétation de l'oubli.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Traduction en français moderne sans effet de style : « je pense que vous n'allez pas tenir compte de ce que je vous ai dit, mais que vous le regretterez plus tard ».

Comment: Je pense que tu as probablement raison. Mais un truc vraiment étrange c'est que l'_oreille de chien_ est une coiffure ou un sobriquet pour la jeunesse dorée sous le Directoire (DHLF). Ensuite, le substantif _repentir_ a un sens dans l'histoire de la coiffure (v. TLFi). Ce genre de coïncidence est vraiment bizarre.

Comment: À la relecture je me suis aperçu que la citation « oreille du chat » figure dans la réponse ; j'ai dû sauter au lien sans jamais revenir en arrière ; en tenir compte dans mon premier commentaire.

Answer (score 1):

Une légère variante de l'interprétation de Gilles :

Le chat est un ersatz d'individu ; il se substitue au responsable qui ne veut pas reconnaître sa faute, au récepteur d'un message qui ne veut pas l'entendre, à la personne concernée qui ne veut pas l'être : c'est n'importe qui sauf nous.

> C'est le chat! [qui l'a fait]. Réponse ironique faite à une personne refusant d'endosser la responsabilité d'un méfait lorsque l'on est certain de sa culpabilité

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chat

De même, « donner sa langue au chat » c'est déplacer vers un individu fictif le soin de chercher la réponse à une question - implicitement, la retourner au questionneur.

Et « mettre quelque chose dans l'oreille du chat », c'est ne pas le mettre dans la sienne : ne pas écouter ou tenir compte d'un conseil.

Comment: Cette idée m'avait brièvement occupé l'esprit ; le chat, trop indépendant, devient bouc émissaire symbolique  en tant que perpétrateur typique de la faute humaine.